# AngularJS and google analytics with site id stored as a constant in root scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, angularjs-scope

I've just created a new application using the yeoman generator for angular, and i can see that google analytics is inserted into index.html.

I have added a config constant to my application and made it available to the rootscope through:

```
angular.module(... ['config',...])
    .run(function ($rootScope,config) {
        $rootScope.config = config
    });
```

Where my config module looks like this

```
angular.module('config', [])
    .constant('config', {analytics:{siteId:'UA-12345-1'}})
```

Now can I change the code to the following such that the analytics site id is inserted and used? Or will the javascript code be evaluated before the contents between the handlebars `{{config.analytics.siteId}}` ?

```
<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
 <script>
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', '{{config.analytics.siteId}}');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I can't seem to detect any calls towards the analytics service, i'm guessing there would be an  ajax request? but that might be because my app is accessed through localhost?

How can i achieve the desired behavior in this case?
Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use $injector.get().

and the answer to your question is no, and your guess is right, the javascript evaluates the ga() function and use the string parameter with the brackets in it.

**updates**

if i were you, i would use module.run().

```
run(function(constValue){

   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', constValue);
   ga('send', 'pageview');

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this module [angular-google-analytics](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics)

It's perfectly working with angular and really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is what i went for, but i still don't think this is the correct answer.

Comment: I know but if you use this module it's easier to configure because you configure it in your angular app config method